# Ruby CSV truncating backtrace

Tags: ruby

Given the following code:

## test.rb

```
require 'csv'

def meth1
  meth2
end

def meth2
  begin
    iter = CSV.foreach('').each # empty file path, will raise exception.
    iter.next
  rescue Exception => e
    puts e
    puts e.backtrace
  end
end

meth1
```

Two questons.
First, why is the backtrace truncated and not showing meth1 or meth2 calls:

```
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen -
ruby test.rb
/Users/x/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/csv.rb:641:in `initialize'
/Users/x/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/csv.rb:641:in `open'
/Users/x/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/csv.rb:641:in `open'
/Users/x/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/csv.rb:510:in `foreach'
test.rb:in `each'
```

Second, the (truncated) backtrace points to line 641 of CSV (using Ruby v 2.7.2).  However line 641 has no initialize() method.  Where is this coming from?

## .rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/csv.rb

```
...
  begin
    f = File.open(filename, mode, **file_opts)  ## line 641
  rescue ArgumentError => e
    raise unless /needs binmode/.match?(e.message) and mode == "r"
    mode = "rb"
    file_opts = {encoding: Encoding.default_external}.merge(file_opts)
    retry
  end
```

If I try another test calling File.open('') directly (instead of through CSV), the resulting backtrace shows everything as expected (including the calls to meth1 and meth2).

Any Ruby gurus out there know what is going on?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand; `#foreach:510` calls `open`, `#open:641` calls `File.open`.

In any case, Ruby backtraces have always been a bit wonky, particularly with local top-level files.

The reason you see the `initialize` is because `foreach` is a class method of CSV, so there's some behind-the-scenes Ruby shenanigans.

You can use the private method `caller_locations`, however:

```rb
puts e.send(:caller_locations)
```

which outputs:

```
test.rb:7:in `meth2'
test.rb:4:in `meth1'
test.rb:20:in `<main>'
```

This is *just* the file's top level methods.

You can play games like `ruby -d` that'll at least get you the line of the script:

```
Exception `LoadError' at /Users/dave/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:1424 - cannot load such file -- rubygems/defaults/operating_system
Exception `LoadError' at /Users/dave/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:1432 - cannot load such file -- rubygems/defaults/ruby
Exception `SyntaxError' at /Users/dave/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/forwardable/impl.rb:5 - /Users/dave/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/forwardable/impl.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input
Exception `SyntaxError' at /Users/dave/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/forwardable/impl.rb:5 - /Users/dave/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/forwardable/impl.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /Users/dave/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/csv.rb:641 - No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen -
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at test.rb:10 - No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen -
/Users/dave/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/csv.rb:641:in `initialize'
/Users/dave/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/csv.rb:641:in `open'
/Users/dave/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/csv.rb:641:in `open'
/Users/dave/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/csv.rb:510:in `foreach'
test.rb:in `each'
```

Along with other noise.

If you really want to blow your mind, inside the `rescue`:

`puts Thread.current.backtrace`

Which outputs:

```
test.rb:21:in `backtrace'
test.rb:21:in `rescue in meth2'
test.rb:7:in `meth2'
test.rb:4:in `meth1'
test.rb:35:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Thanks!  
I am really trying to figure out what the wonkiness of Ruby is and WHY the backtrace is truncated for CSV.  Using caller, or stitching backtrace() from the context before the failing method PLUS the truncated CSV output is possible but problematic.  In application tests that go through hundreds of layers in the call stack (Rails), the test frameworks just bubble up `exception.backtrace`.  If the backtrace itself is truncated, I have to go into the weeds and find it manually.

Comment: @jpgeek In general for non CLI apps you won’t have this issue (and there’s better_errors, although I don’t know if that’s been maintained). It is rare to be completely at sea in a Rails app (other than the standard Rails confusions).

Comment: I am hitting this in Rails.   RSpec/ MiniTest currently just show the above four line trace - pretty useless for finding where my code has gone awry.  Would be nice to have the full trace but looks like that won't happen soon.  Thanks again.